# Snowpack dev isn't detecting file changes

Tags: file, windows-subsystem-for-linux, snowpack

*Snowpack won't detect any changes no matter what I do.*

**I use Windows 10 with WSL2 and VSCode version 1.51**

*I don't believe this is a VSCode issue as even in zsh it doesn't detect changes*

I've tried 
`sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 && sudo sysctl -p --system` 
and 
`echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/40-max-user-watches.conf && sudo sysctl --system` 
Still no luck :( 
The template is [@snowpack/app-template-react-typescript](https://github.com/snowpackjs/snowpack/tree/master/create-snowpack-app/app-template-react-typescript) 
If you need any extra info ask me in the comments ⬇

Answer (score 0):

***If your using WSL2 keep your projects and files in the WSL "realm" directory***

***If its WSL1 any directory is fine***

*Answering my own question lol*